# Arduino Compare Weights of an Array

Tags: arrays, arduino, sensors, robotics

I am trying to get a sensor to scan around and mark an object by assigning a 1 to that position. The positions are from 30 60 90 120 150 [ 0 0 0 0 0]. I then wanted to take that aray and compare it to memory ( tempArray vs memArray) and decide which way to turn. Essentially obstacle avoidance, any suggestions on how to implement this with arrays?

```
void scan() {
servo.write(30);
delay(350);
rScan = echodis();
 if (rScan > distanceLimit) {
tempArray[4] = 1;
  }
servo.write(60);
delay(350);
rDiagScan = echodis();
if (rDiagScan > distanceLimit) {
  tempArray[3] = 1;
  }
servo.write(90);
delay(350);
cScan = echodis();
if (cScan > distanceLimit) {
  tempArray[2] = 1;
  }
servo.write(120);
delay(350);
lDiagScan = echodis();
if (lDiagScan > distanceLimit) {
  tempArray[1] = 1;
 }
servo.write(150);
delay(350);
lScan = echodis();
if (lScan > distanceLimit) {
  tempArray[0] = 1;
}
scanCount++;

servo.write(120);
delay(350);
lDiagScan = echodis();
if (lDiagScan > distanceLimit) {
  tempArray[1] = 1;
 } servo.write(90);
delay(350);
cScan = echodis();
if (cScan > distanceLimit) {
  tempArray[2] = 1;
  }
servo.write(60);
delay(350);
rDiagScan = echodis();
if (rDiagScan > distanceLimit) {
  tempArray[3] = 1;
}
servo.write(30);
delay(350);
rScan = echodis();
if (rScan > distanceLimit) {
  tempArray[4] = 1;
}
scanCount++;
//if(scanCount = 4){
 //memset(tempArray, 0, sizeof(tempArray));
//}
//return (tempArray);




 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve such problems in repetition, here's one.

The approach here is to let state and data drive the operations rather than massively repetitive, bug prone code.  Also consider the importance of defining minimums, maximums, constants etc in one place.

```
#define SERVO_SETTLE_MILLIS  350
#define SERVO_STEP  30
#define SERVO_SAMPLE_LEN  5
#define OUTLIER 1
#define INLIER 0

byte scan_count = 0; // when even or 0, position starts at 30. when odd, position starts at 150.

void scan(byte* pSampleArray, const uint16_t maxDistance) {

  byte direction = scan_count % 2 == 0;
  byte servo_position = direction ? (SERVO_SAMPLE_LEN * SERVO_STEP) : 0;
  byte sample_index = direction ? SERVO_SAMPLE_LEN : -1;

  for (byte i = 0; i < SERVO_SAMPLE_LEN; i++) {

    // direction == 0 == servo position starts at 30 (initial)
    if (direction) {
      sample_index--; // e.g. 4,3,2,1,0
      servo_position += SERVO_STEP; // e.g. 30,60,90,120,150
    }
    else
    {
      sample_index++; // e.g. 0,1,2,3,4
      servo_position -= SERVO_STEP;; // e.g. 150,120,90,60,30
    }
    // position servo
    servo.write(servo_position);
    // settling time
    delay(SERVO_SETTLE_MILLIS);
    // sample = 1 if outlier, 0 otherwise
    pSampleArray[sample_index] = echodis() > maxDistance ? OUTLIER : INLIER;
  }

  scan_count++; // implies direction stepping for next call to scan.
}
```

Of course care must be taken that pSampleArray can accomodate 5 samples.

You don't speak of what you plan to do with "arrays" which is probably the real meat of your project, but for example consider function **foo**

```
void foo(const uint16_t maxDistance) {
  byte sample1[SERVO_SAMPLE_LEN];
  byte sample2[SERVO_SAMPLE_LEN];
  scan(sample1, maxDistance);
  delay(1000);
  scan(sample2, maxDistance);
  //
  // process your samples
  //
}
```

Good luck!